# The non-content part of making a newsstand compatible app

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad, newsstand-kit

I am working on a newsstand magazine and I have done the content (with great help from the Laker Compendium), but can't manage to do the part concerning the app's store view and server downloading.
There is really a small number of tutorials and such help on newsstand and the only one I found to be helpful in some other aspects, doesn't really explain well this part.

Simply, what I'm asking is if I have created content (as a single app), how do I get it to work with a store and future issues?
Is there a downloadable project I can adapt to my own server?

Answer (score 2):

Laker does not yet have newsstand capability. You can try to add it yourself. This is the best tutorial I have found: 
http://www.viggiosoft.com/blog/blog/2011/10/17/ios-newsstand-tutorial/

Also, I recommend the wwdc video talks that you can download for free on iTunes about newsstand. You will need to build your own server to host the files. I'm doing the same using Google App Engine. This is a non-trivial project.